# Merging too many small files into single large files in Datalake using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I Have Following Directory Structure In HDFS.

```
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-1.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-2.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-3.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-1.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-2.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-3.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-1.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-2.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-3.txt
```

I want to Merge the files DayWise.

```
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-1.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-1.txt
/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-1.txt
```

I have used below code.

```
val inputDir="/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/"
val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val hdfsConf = new Configuration();
val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf)
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val baseFolder = new Path(inputDir)
val files = baseFolder.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration).listStatus(baseFolder).map(_.getPath.toString)
for (path <- files) {
var Folder_Path = fs.listStatus(new Path(path)).map(_.getPath).toList
for (eachfolder <- Folder_Path) {
var New_Folder_Path: String = eachfolder.toString
var Fs1 = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
var FilePath = Fs1.listStatus(new Path(s"${New_Folder_Path}")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).toList
var NewFiles = Fs1.listStatus(new Path(s"${New_Folder_Path}")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath.getName).toList
```

"FilePath" : Generating the List of Complete Path for all the files recursively.

```
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-1.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-2.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=01/part-3.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-1.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-2.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=02/part-3.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-1.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-2.txt)
List(/user/hdfs/landing_zone/year=2021/month=11/day=03/part-3.txt)
```

"NewFiles" : - Generating the list of FileNames for all the files recursively

```
List(part-1.txt)
List(part-2.txt)
List(part-3.txt)
List(part-1.txt)
List(part-2.txt)
List(part-3.txt)
List(part-1.txt)
List(part-2.txt)
List(part-3.txt)
```

Can Someone Suggest/Guide me How should I modify the code so that It can Generate the files DayWise and merge 3 file(1 day=3 files) into a single file (1 day = 1 file) recursively for all the days.

Comment: Is this in a hive table?

Comment: are you querying this text?  Are you consuming it with a pipeline down stream that users should be querying?  Why are you looking to concatenate files?  Is it for space saving or query performance?

Comment: we are not querying this text. Its just a backup from kafka.since kafka's retention period is 24 hrs. so In case if some data is missing  from regular flow,we can just repush  from raw data in kafka and reprocess the same.

Answer (score 0):

They're are easier ways that getting into low level manipulations.I would suggest "picking the table up and putting it back down"

Literally, create a table based on the files, write it to a new table. This should concatenate the small files. (Without you having to manipulate it)

If you have created a hive table based on this you could [use hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate) to do the work:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION (partition_key = 'partition_value' [, ...])] CONCATENATE;
```

Comment: Yes @Matt Andruff. But this functionality only available in orc file, Not In textfile.

SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Concatenate/Merge only supported for RCFile and ORCFile formats (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: I would definitely suggest that you consider using a different format than text.  Parquet/Orc/Avro what ever you prefer but plain text has a very poor performance.

Comment: This is the raw data which we are storing since last more than 2 years. so cannot change the format at this time. So trying to merge small files using spark.